# Next.js : error - ./node_modules/etag/index.js:22:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' null

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, next.js, fs

```js
export class SpringApiError extends ApiError {
    readonly timestamp: string;
    readonly path: string;
    constructor(dto: ServerErrorDto) {
        super(dto.status, dto.message);
        this.timestamp = dto.timestamp;
        this.name = dto.error;
        this.path = dto.path;
    }

    toString() {
        return `
            ${this.stack} | ${this.name} | ${this.message}
        `
    }

}

interface ServerErrorDto {
    timestamp?: string,
    status: number,
    error: string
    message: string
    path?: string
}
```

For some reason, merely extending `ApiError` gives me an that error from the `etag` module.
Any Idea why?
Is this normal?

I'm just looking for a lesson maybe... I'm perfectly happy extending `Error` instead.

Comment: Where does `ApiError` come from? That's not a JS standard built-in error type.

Comment: @juliomalves it's from Next.js

Comment: @Ghislain try to run: `npm run build` then read and google by the error message. Also, read this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7755#issuecomment-624544303
In my case, my code editor's autocomplete imported wrong function. This caused that behaviour. I deleted that wrong import and nextjs got to work well.